# Формула Бернули (Пуассона)

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Работают 50 магазинов по продаже телевизоров. Вероятность отказа покупателю в магазинах равна 0,1. Считая, что ассортимент товара в каждом магазине формируется независимо от других, определить вероятность того, что покупатель получит отказ более чем в 10 магазинах.
Хотел использовать формулу Пуассона, но по условию задачи не попадаю под ограничения n > 50 и p<0.1

Comment: Он идет во все 50 и считает те, где ему отказали, или надо посчитать вероятность, что в первых 11 ему не повезло?

Comment: Он идет во все 50 магазинов

Comment: Тогда это обычное биномиальное распределение, посчитать соответствующую сумму (или оценить исходя из аппроксимации нормальным).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычное биномиальное распределение. Вероятность, что ему откажут в k магазинах -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раз надо посчитать вероятность, что ему откажут *более* чем в 10 - надо считать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для `p = 0.1` эта сумма равна `0.0093546`.

Точно так же можно посчитать, что ему *не* откажут в не более чем 10 магазинах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что, понятно, то же самое...

Можно оценить значение исходя из нормального распределения - 50 уже достаточно большое значение...

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*